# How to responsively order right side blocks to top and bottom of left side block with bootstrap

Tags: responsive-design, responsive, bootstrap-5, grid-system

I have the mobile design of three blocks:

```
 _
|A|
|_|
|B|
|_|
|C|
|_|
```

I want to achive the following responsive md design with bootstrap5 grid system.

```
 ___
|B|A|
| |_|
| |C|
|_|_|
```

I've tried different approaches, 3 rows, rows in rows, ordering etc. but I can't figure out the responsive solution, without redundancy.

Comment: The first structure to be the mobile design, and the second is the desktop design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```css
#a,
#b-desktop,
#b-mobile,
#c {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container-fluid>.row {
  height: 100vh;
}

#b-desktop {
  height: 100%;
}

#b-mobile {
  height: 50vh;
}

#a {
  height: 50vh;
}

#c {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 d-md-block d-none" id="b-desktop">B</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12" id="a">A</div>
          <div class="col-12 d-md-none d-block" id="b-mobile">B</div>
          <div class="col-12" id="c">C</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```